# trouble installing matplotlib-cpp

Tags: c++, matplotlib, installation, cmake

Hi I am trying to install the library matplotlib-cpp on an Arch system. This is what I got:

```
[luca@luca-mb matplotlib-cpp-master]$ make      
mkdir -p examples/build
g++ -o examples/build/lines3d examples/lines3d.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.9 -I/usr/include/python3.9 -I/home/luca/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -std=c++11 -Wno-conversion  -L/usr/lib -lpython3.9 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -lm 
examples/lines3d.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
examples/lines3d.cpp:24:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘plot3(std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’
   24 |     plt::plot3(x, y, z, keywords);
      |                                 ^
In file included from examples/lines3d.cpp:1:
examples/../matplotlibcpp.h:586:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Numeric> void matplotlibcpp::plot3(const std::vector<Numeric>&, const std::vector<Numeric>&, const std::vector<Numeric>&, long int, const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’
  586 | void plot3(const std::vector<Numeric> &x,
      |      ^~~~~
examples/../matplotlibcpp.h:586:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
examples/lines3d.cpp:24:25: note:   cannot convert ‘keywords’ (type ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’) to type ‘long int’
   24 |     plt::plot3(x, y, z, keywords);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:38: examples/build/lines3d] Error 1
```

I have tried installing and all the necessary python libraries for this but had no lock so far. Anyone able to see where the problem is?

Thanks.